# Xcode will not open "Required content for iOS Simulator is missing"

Tags: xcode

I am trying to open XCode downloaded from https://xcodereleases.com/ (*Xcode_X.X.X.xip*). Unzip using "Archive Utility". After hours of waiting then when trying to open it, I got the following error "Required content for iOS Simulator is missing".

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the **Xcode xip** file from https://xcodereleases.com/ instead of getting the app through the **macOS App Store** then follow these steps.

1. Copy the **Xcode_X.X.X.xip** to **/Applications**
2. Open a **terminal** and run the following commands (command line xip utility)

   ➜ cd /Applications

   ➜ xip --expand Xcode_X.X.X.xip

   xip: signing certificate was “Software Update” (validation not attempted)

   xip: expanded items from “/Applications/ Xcode_X.X.X.xip”

**Notes:**  ***The error is actually due to the way that the xip file has been decompressed.***

[Refs](https://nachega.com/2021/08/08/how-to-solve-required-content-for-ios-simulator-is-missing-or-required-content-for-tvos-simulator-is-missing/)